# version code shows different from local.properties file when l install the app on the real device

Tags: android, flutter, apk, version

I am currently developing an application that version of this app in pubspec.yaml is 1.0.0+4  and **local.properties** file updated.

local.properties

```
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=4
```

When I build a release APK from below command:

> flutter build apk --split-per-abi

And install **app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk** on a real device the version code is 1004.
I've built several apps and installed them on several devices but I don't understand why the version code differences.

Comment: run your app before building release app. This updates the version and versionapp in local.properties file

Answer (score 1):

Set your versionCode in defaultConfig of `android/app/build.gradle`. For example

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com."
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 132
    versionName "4.0.32"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: I do this and build APK again, but my version code still 1004.

Comment: before release build. Can you check the version code in debug build?